# How can I change the stacking order of my columns?

Tags: css

My webpage contains three "pages"; a red page, a green page, and a blue page. Each page is sticky and has a size = 100vw x 100vh. The red page contains a lefthand column, the green page contains a center column, and the blue page contains a righthand column. When the webpage is scrolled the green page slides up over the red page and then the blue page slides up over the green page.

What I want to achieve is that the lefthand column remains visible when the green page is scrolled up, and that the lefthand and center columns remain visible when the blue page is scrolled up. Thus when the webpage has been scrolled to the bottom there will be a blue background and all three columns will be visible.

In the css you will see that I have tried to accomplish my objective by increasing the z-index of the columns. My understanding of why this does not work is that each sticky div establishes its own stacking context.

Can anyone tell me how to achieve my objective using css? Failing that I am going to resort to javascript.

```css
* {
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
    height: 700vh;
    background-color: black;
}


.page {
    position: sticky;
    top: 0;

    width: 100vw;
    height: 100vh;

    padding: 5%;
}

#page1, #page4 {
    background-color: red;
}

#page2, #page5 {
    background-color: green;
}

#page3, #page6 {
    background-color: blue;
}

.column {
    float: left;
    width: 32.3%;
    height: 100%;

    margin-left: .5%;
    margin-right: .5%;

    background-color: #fffff4;

    position: relative;
    top: 0;
    z-index: 2;
}


#page1 :is(.column2, .column3) {
    visibility: hidden;
}

#page2 :is(.column1, .column3) {
    visibility: hidden;
}

#page3 :is(.column1, .column2) {
    visibility: hidden;
}

#explanation {
    color: white;
    background-color: black;
    font-size: 5vh;
}

#page4 :is(.column2, .column3) {
    visibility: hidden;
}

#page5 :is(.column3) {
    visibility: hidden;
}
```

```html
<div id="page1" class="page">
    <div class="column column1"></div>
    <div class="column column2"></div>
    <div class="column column3"></div>
</div>

<div id="page2" class="page">
    <div class="column column1"></div>
    <div class="column column2"></div>
    <div class="column column3"></div>
</div>

<div id="page3" class="page">
    <div class="column column1"></div>
    <div class="column column2"></div>
    <div class="column column3"></div>
</div>

<p id="explanation" class="page"> The next 3 pages illustrate the result that I am trying to produce.
Note that in this illustration the lefthand column is being replicated on the 2nd and 3rd pages and that the center column is being replicated on the 3rd page. I would prefer not to replicate the columns but rather to have them remain visible. Note also that I have said nothing about the ultimate content of the columns. This snippet is a simplied version of what I ultimately intend to produce.</p>

<div id="page4" class="page">
    <div class="column column1"></div>
    <div class="column column2"></div>
    <div class="column column3"></div>
</div>

<div id="page5" class="page">
    <div class="column column1"></div>
    <div class="column column2"></div>
    <div class="column column3"></div>
</div>

<div id="page6" class="page">
    <div class="column column1"></div>
    <div class="column column2"></div>
    <div class="column column3"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: I'm not sure if I fully understand the requirements, but this is my best interpretation of the question ([JS Fiddle demo](https://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/sq2ngf8y/)), is it anywhere near your intended result?

Comment: Hi David. Thank you for the fiddle. It is near but not on the money. And shucks, I really tried to be clear with my explanation :-( .  When the green page finishes scrolling to the top there should be a left and a center column but only green background. When the blue page finishes scrolling to the top there should be a left and a center and a right column but only blue background. The backgrounds change, the columns accumulate.

Comment: I could duplicate the left column on the 2nd and 3rd pages, and duplicate the center column on the 3rd page. I'm hoping for something more modular.

Comment: I'm sorry, I really aren't getting this; would it be possible to add a couple of simple pictures to illustrate? I don't think I understand what you mean by "columns," in this context.

Comment: Take the background off the individual ‘ pages’ and put one three color linear gradient background on the body at 100vh intervals.

Comment: I have expanded the code snippet so that it illustrates the result that I want to achieve.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is this what you wanted?
I used grid and sticky to make it work

Basic version:

```
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  background-color: grey;
}

.column {
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
  height: 100vh;
  position: sticky;
  top: 0;
}

.columns_grid {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr 1fr;
  grid-template-rows: 100vh;
  gap: 0px 20px;
}

.column {
  background-color: lavender;
}

.column,
.content {
  padding: 20px;
}


/*    Page1*/

.content.page1 {
  background-color: mistyrose;
  grid-row: 1;
  grid-column: 2/4;
}

.column.page1 {
  grid-column: 1;
}


/*    Page2*/

.content.page2 {
  background-color: violet;
  grid-row: 2;
  grid-column: 3;
}

.column.page2 {
  grid-column: 2;
}


/*    Page3*/

.content.page3 {
  background-color: mediumvioletred;
}

.column.page3 {
  grid-column: 3;
}
```

```html
<section class="columns_grid">
  <!--    This is the 1° section-->
  <div class="column page1">
    hello world N°1
  </div>
  <div class="content page1">
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet N°1
  </div>

  <!--    This is the 2° section-->
  <div class="column page2">
    hello world N°2
  </div>
  <div class="content page2">
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet N°2
  </div>


  <!--    This is the 3° section-->
  <div class="column page3">
    hello world N°3
  </div>

</section>
```

Full version (looks more like you want to) :

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  background-color: grey;
}

.column {
  position: sticky;
  top: 0;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

.columns_grid {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr 1fr;
  grid-template-rows: 100vh;
  gap: 0px 20px;
}

.content .inner_content {
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
}

.column .inner_content {
  background-color: white;
  padding-top: 20px;
  height: 80%;
  width: 100%;
}


/*    Page1*/

.content.page1 {
  background-color: red;
  grid-row: 1;
  grid-column: 1/4;
}

.column.page1 {
  grid-column: 1;
  grid-row: 1;
}

.page1 .inner_content {
  grid-column: 2/4;
}


/*    Page2*/

.content.page2 {
  background-color: green;
  grid-row: 2;
  grid-column: 1/4;
}

.column.page2 {
  grid-column: 2;
  grid-row: 2;
}

.page2 .inner_content {
  grid-column: 3/4;
}


/*    Page3*/

.content.page3 {
  background-color: blue;
  grid-row: 3;
  grid-column: 1/4;
}

.column.page3 {
  grid-column: 3;
  grid-row: 3;
}
```

```html
<section class="columns_grid">
  <!--    This is the 1° section-->
  <div class="column page1">
    <div class="inner_content">
      hello world N°1
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="content columns_grid page1">
    <div class="inner_content">

      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet N°1
    </div>
  </div>

  <!--    This is the 2° section-->
  <div class="column page2">
    <div class="inner_content">
      hello world N°2
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="content columns_grid page2">
    <div class="inner_content">
      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet N°2
    </div>
  </div>


  <!--    This is the 3° section-->
  <div class="column page3">
    <div class="inner_content">
      hello world N°3
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="content columns_grid page3">
  </div>

</section>
```

Comment: Close enough (why the lorem ipsum content?). I’ll take it. Thank you.

Comment: This was to show you what to do if you want to add content next to the columns

Comment: Okay. I copied and tweaked - exactly what I was after! Thx, SioGabx.